# How to transliterate in QGIS using Python 3

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, python-3, qgis-3, transliteration

I am QGIS user but beginner in Python.
I figured out how to transliterate Georgian script into Latin using this module (https://pypi.org/project/transliterate/).

```
from transliterate import translit, get_available_language_codes

text= 'საქართველო'

from transliterate.discover import autodiscover
autodiscover()

from transliterate.base import TranslitLanguagePack, registry

class MyGeorgianLanguagePack(TranslitLanguagePack):
    language_code = "my-ka"
    language_name = "MyGeorgian"
    mapping = (
    "აბგდევზთიკლმნოპჟრსტუფქღყშჩცძწჭხჯჰ", # Source script
    "abgdevztiklmnopzhrstupkghkshchtsdztschkhjh", # Target script
    )
    pre_processor_mapping = {
        "ჟ":  "zh",
        "რ":  "r",
        "ს":  "s",
        "ტ":  "t",
        "უ":  "u",    
        "ფ":  "p",
        "ქ":  "k",
        "ღ":  "gh",
        "ყ":  "k",
        "შ":  "sh",
        "ჩ":  "ch",
        "ც":  "ts",
        "ძ":  "dz",
        "წ":  "ts",
        "ჭ":  "ch",
        "ხ":  "kh",
        "ჯ":  "j",
        "ჰ":  "h"
    }

registry.register(MyGeorgianLanguagePack)

print((translit(text, 'my-ka')).title())

# Sakartvelo
```

But now I am interested, how can I incorporate this script in QGIS to automatically transliterate Georgian names in Latin script from one field to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, strong efforts do its job.

Here is the answer:

```
from transliterate import translit, get_available_language_codes

from transliterate.discover import autodiscover
autodiscover()

from transliterate.base import TranslitLanguagePack, registry

class MyGeorgianLanguagePack(TranslitLanguagePack):
    language_code = "my-ka"
    language_name = "MyGeorgian"
    mapping = (
    "აბგდევზთიკლმნოპჟრსტუფქღყშჩცძწჭხჯჰ", # Source script
    "abgdevztiklmnopzhrstupkghkshchtsdztschkhjh", # Target script
    )
    pre_processor_mapping = {
        "ჟ":  "zh",
        "რ":  "r",
        "ს":  "s",
        "ტ":  "t",
        "უ":  "u",    
        "ფ":  "p",
        "ქ":  "k",
        "ღ":  "gh",
        "ყ":  "k",
        "შ":  "sh",
        "ჩ":  "ch",
        "ც":  "ts",
        "ძ":  "dz",
        "წ":  "ts",
        "ჭ":  "ch",
        "ხ":  "kh",
        "ჯ":  "j",
        "ჰ":  "h"
    }

registry.register(MyGeorgianLanguagePack)

# pre-pyqgis code above

# pyqgis code below

layer=QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(False), "any_layer_name_here", "postgres")
features=layer.getFeatures()

layer_provider=layer.dataProvider()

layer.startEditing()
for f in features:
    id=f.id()
    text=f.attributes()[1]
    transl=(translit(text, 'my-ka')).title()
    attr_value={2:transl}
    layer_provider.changeAttributeValues({id:attr_value})
layer.commitChanges()

# field under index [1] will be transliterated into field under index [2]
```

**UPDATE**

If your field contains NULL values, modify the part of the script like below.

```
    for f in features:
        id=f.id()
        text=f.attributes()[1]
        if f.attributes()[1] == None:
            nodata = NULL
            attr_value1 = {2:nodata}
            layer_provider.changeAttributeValues({id:attr_value1})
        else:
            transl=(translit(text, 'my-ka')).title()
            attr_value2={2:transl}
            layer_provider.changeAttributeValues({id:attr_value2})
    layer.commitChanges()

# field under index [1] will be transliterated into field under index [2], NULL values will stay as NULL.
```